# Proof of identity about generalized binomial sequences.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, summation, markov-chains, martingales

I was going through this old question about a wealthy gambler: 
[Gambler with infinite bankroll reaching his target](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202821/gambler-with-infinite-bankroll-reaching-his-target?rq=1). The answer relies on the following identities from [Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf) (equation numbers as they appear in the book).

$$B_2(z) = \sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty \frac{{2t+1\choose t}}{2t+1} z^t = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z} \tag{5.68}$$

$$(B_2(z))^k = \left(\sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty {2t+1\choose t}\frac{1}{2t+1} z^t\right)^k = \sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty {2t+k \choose t} \frac{k}{2t+k}z^t \tag{5.70}$$

The expression on the far right of (5.70) is particularly interesting since  [it is the stopping time of a wealthy gambler targeting $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043013/probability-that-random-walk-will-reach-state-k-for-the-first-time-on-step-n). 
It is also fascinating since $k$ seems to simply march into the infinite summation and replace $1$, somehow taking care of all the cross terms in the process.

I read through the chapter to see if I could find a proof for these identities (both of which I verified numerically).

Tracing my way back, I found the following (equivalent) definition of $B_u(z)$.

$$B_u(z) = \sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty \frac{ut \choose t}{(u-1)t+1} z^t \tag{5.58}$$

Then they simply state:

$$(B_u(z))^k = \sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty {ut+k \choose t} \frac{k}{ut+k} z^t \tag{5.60}$$

However, no proof is provided for these. So, I'm still scratching my head wondering how to prove (5.68) and (5.70).

---

My attempts:

For (5.70), we can say that in order for the gambler to reach $k$\$, he has to first reach $1$\$ and then repeat that feat $k$ times. This provides a rough sketch, but I'm still fascinated by the mechanical details (and (5.60) has no such interpretation in terms of gamblers).

For (5.68), I tried some of the approaches in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049876/race-of-the-wealthy-gamblers-how-do-i-get-this-closed-form?noredirect=1&lq=1).

First, Mathematica couldn't find a nice expression for the partial summation. So, @robojohn's approach probably won't work because if there were a function whose diff made up the terms of $B_2(z)$, the partial summation would have a nice expression in terms of that function.

Next, I tried @Marcus Scheuer's approach and got:

$$\frac{a_{t+1}}{a_t} = \frac{t+\frac 1 2}{t+2}(4z) = \frac{\frac{-1}{2}^\underline{t}}{-2^\underline{t}} (4z)$$

This doesn't work either since we don't get the $a+b=c+d$ condition required for the corollary he used and the $4z$ term interferes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At first we show (5.68). Using the *[Binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{B_2(z)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2z}\left(1-\sum_{t=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{t}(-4z)^t\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2z}\sum_{t=1}^\infty\binom{1/2}{t}(-1)^{t+1}2^{2t}z^t\\
> &=\sum_{t=1}^\infty\binom{1/2}{t}(-1)^{t+1}2^{2t-1}z^{t-1}\\
> &=\sum_{t=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{t+1}(-1)^t2^{2t+1}z^t\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{t=0}^\infty\binom{2t+1}{t}\frac{1}{2t+1}z^t}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

The last line (1) follows since we have
\begin{align*}
\binom{1/2}{t+1}&=\frac{1}{(t+1)!}\prod_{j=0}^t\left(\frac{1}{2}-j\right)=\frac{1}{(t+1)!}\cdot\frac{(-1)^{t+1}}{2^{t+1}}\prod_{j=0}^t(2j-1)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^t(2t-1)!!}{2^{t+1}(t+1)!}=\frac{(-1)^t(2t)!}{2^{t+1}(t+1)!(2t)!!}=\frac{(-1)^t(2t)!}{2^{2t+1}(t+1)!t!}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^t}{2^{2t+1}}\binom{2t+1}{t}\frac{1}{2t+1}
\end{align*}

> ... and now the generalisation (5.70). In the following we use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^t]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^t$ in a series.
>
> We observe the generating function $zB_2(z)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)$ has the *compositional inverse*
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(z-z^2\right)^{\langle-1\rangle}=zB_2(z)}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> since
> \begin{align*}
> zB_2(z)-\left(zB_2(z)\right)^2&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)^2\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\left(1-2\sqrt{1-4z}+1-4z\right)\\
> &=z
> \end{align*}

The nice representation of the compositional inverse indicates we could apply the *Lagrange Inversion Formula* which gives us the coefficients of the $k$-th power of the generating function $zB_2(z)$.

Here we use it according to Theorem 5.4.2 in *[Enumerative Combinatorics, vol. 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AKE1USM)* by R.P. Stanley.

**Theorem:** Let $F(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots\in xK[[z]]$, where $a_1\ne 0$ (and $\mathrm{char} K=0$), and let $k,t\in \mathrm{Z}$. Then
\begin{align*}
t[z^t]F^{\langle-1\rangle}(z)^k=k[z^{t-k}]\left(\frac{z}{F(z)}\right)^t\tag{3}
\end{align*}

> Applying (3) with $F^{\langle -1\rangle}(z)=zB_2(z)$ we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[z^t]\left(zB_2(z)\right)^k}&=\frac{k}{t}[z^{t-k}]\left(\frac{z}{z-z^2}\right)^t\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{k}{t}[z^{t-k}]\frac{1}{\left(1-z\right)^t}\\
> &=\frac{k}{t}[z^{t-k}]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-t}{j}(-z)^j\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{k}{t}[z^{t-k}]\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{t+j-1}{j}z^j\tag{6}\\
> &=\frac{k}{t}\binom{2t-k-1}{t-1}\tag{7}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{k}{2t-k}\binom{2t-k}{t-k}}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4) we  use $F^{\langle -1\rangle}(z)=zB_2(z)=\left(z-z^2\right)^{\langle -1\rangle}$ from (2).
- In (5) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (6) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^{q}$.
- In (7) we select the  coefficient of $z^{t-k}$.
- In (8) we use  the binomial identities $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$ and  $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.

> We  finally obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(zB_2(z)\right)^k}&=\left(\sum_{t=0}^\infty\binom{2t+1}{t}\frac{1}{2t+1}z^{t+1}\right)^k\tag{9}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{t=1}^\infty\binom{2t-1}{t-1}\frac{1}{2t-1}z^t\right)^k\tag{10}\\
> &=\sum_{t=k}^\infty\binom{2t-k}{t-k}\frac{k}{2t-k}z^t\tag{11}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=z^k\sum_{t=0}^\infty\binom{2t+k}{t}\frac{k}{2t+k}z^t}\tag{12}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (9) we use the  identity (5.68)  resp. (1).
- In (10) we shift the index $t$  by one to have an expansion in terms with factor $z^t$.
- In (11) we apply (8), the representation thanks to the Lagrange inversion formula.
- In (12) we shift the index to start with $t=0$.

Note that (12) can also be expressed as:

$$(zB_2(z))^k = z^k \sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty {2t+k-1 \choose t}\frac{k}{t+k}z^t$$

Comment: Thanks for all your help, Markus! This was the direction I was beginning to consider. Do you have any ideas for why the $k$ marches into (5.70) like that? If not, I'll wait a few more hours and mark this the correct answer (being content with the reach +1\$ $k$ times argument).

Comment: @RohitPandey: You're welcome. I'm thinking about the other identity. But in fact I can start working on it not before tomorrow evening. Maybe some other can post an answer earlier than me.

Comment: Sure, no hurry. Much appreciated.

Comment: @RohitPandey: I've added a proof of (5.70). Regards,

Comment: Thanks, will take me some time to digest this. Appreciate the exposure to these beautiful techniques. Wish I could upvote multiple times :)

Comment: @RohitPandey: Many thanks for granting a bounty. This is extraordinarily kind of you. Currently I'm busy, but soon I will  give you some references, which might help you to dig somewhat deeper into the concepts of the Lagrange inversion formula.

Comment: No, Thank you for the great answer, I thought I'd never have a chance to grasp this (since the original reference in Knuth's book was in French and he gave no proof). Have tried to go through your proof, but will need a few more readings to fully grasp it. Certainly looking forward to your references :)

Comment: @RohitPandey: I've added some comments. I recommend to go through the first part of section 5.4 in *[Stanleys book](https://www.amazon.com/Enumerative-Combinatorics-Cambridge-Advanced-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00AKE1USM)* till the end of theorem 5.4.2. An accessible approach is given in *[Lagrange Inversion: when and how](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Lagrange-Inversion%3A-when-and-how-Merlini-Sprugnoli/9d3062a6874642d7df8d404f680c81a8321f978f)* by  D. Merlini. A great survey with many references is presented in *[Lagrange Inversion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05988)* by I.M. Gessel.

Comment: Thanks, I now follow your proof apart from Lagrange inversion formula (and I'll surely get there with your excellent references). You had two typos in your answer as well and MO wouldn't let me make the corrections unless there were 6 characters. So, I made the two corrections and added an alternate formula for the sum in the end for my own reference (feel free to delete that last added formula if you like).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach I came across thanks to /u/whatkindofred on [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/adajkf/identity_describing_stopping_time_of_wealthy/edjnf8y/?context=3) for proving (5.68). This approach starts from the LHS.

Let's suppose:

$$F(z) = \sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty a_t z_t =  \sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty \frac{2t \choose t}{t+1} z^t$$

It is easy to see that:

$$(t+1)a_t = (4t-2)a_{t-1}\tag{1.1}$$

Further suppose that:

$$G(z) = zF(z) = \sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty a_t z^{t+1}$$
So,
$$G'(z) = \sum\limits_{t=0}^\infty (t+1)a_t z^t$$

Using (1.1)
$$G'(z)= a_0 + \sum\limits_{t=1}^\infty(4t-2)a_{t-1}z^t$$

Since $a_0=1$,
$$G'(z) = 1+4 \sum\limits_{t=1}^\infty t a_{t-1} z^t - 2 \sum\limits_{t=1}^\infty a_{t-1}z_t$$
$$= 1+ 4 \sum_{t=1}^\infty (t+1)a_t z^{t+1} - 2 \sum\limits_{t=1}^\infty a_{t-1}z^t$$
$$G'(z)= 1+4zG'(z)-2G(z)\tag{1.2}$$

But since $G(z)=zF(z)$,

$$G'(z)=F(z)+zF'(z)$$
Substituting into (1.2) we get:

$$F(z)+zF'(z)=1+2zF(z)+4z^2F'(z)$$
$$(4z^2-z)F'(z)+(2z-1)F(z)+1=0$$
$$F'(z) + g(z) F(z) = h(z) \tag{1.3}$$

Where,
$$g(z) = \frac{2z-1}{4z^2-z}$$
$$h(z)=\frac{1}{z-4z^2}$$

Multiplying both sides of (1.3) by $e^{\int\limits_{0}^x g(t)dt}$ we get,

$$e^{\int\limits_{0}^z g(t)dt} F'(z) + e^{\int\limits_{0}^x g(t)dt} g(z)F(z)=h(z)e^{\int\limits_{0}^z g(t)dt}$$

$$=> \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(F(z)e^{\int\limits_{0}^z g(t)dt}\right) = h(z) e^{\int\limits_{0}^z g(t)dt}$$

$$=> F(z)e^{\int\limits_{0}^z g(t)dt} = \int\limits_{y=0}^z h(y) e^{\int\limits_{0}^y g(t)dt}\tag{1.4}$$

Now, let's address the integrals.

$$\int g(z)dz = -\int \frac{2z-1}{z-4z^2}$$

$$ = \int \frac{-2}{1-4z}dz + \int \frac{dz}{z(1-4z)}$$

$$=\frac{\log(1-4z)}{2} + \int \frac{4z+(1-4z)}{z(1-4z)}dz$$

$$=\frac{\log(1-4z)}{2}+ 4 \int \frac{dz}{1-4z}+\int \frac{dz}{z}$$

$$=\frac{\log(1-4z)}{2}- \log(1-4z) +\log(z)$$

$$=> \int g(z) dz = \log\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)+b_1 $$

And so,

$$e^{\int g(z)dz} = c_1\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-4z}}\tag{1.5}$$

And this means,
$$\int h(z) e^{\int g(z)dz} = \int \frac{1}{z(1-4z)} c_2\frac{z}{\sqrt{1-4z}}dz$$

$$ = \int c_2(1-4z)^{-\frac 3 2}dz = \frac{c_2}{\sqrt{1-4z}}+c_3\tag{1.6}$$

Substituting (1.5) and (1.6) into (1.4) yields:

$$F(z)=\frac{d_1 + d_2 \sqrt{1-4z}}{z}$$

But we know that $F(0)=1$ and for the above equation to not blow up at $z=0$ we must have $d_1=-d_2=d$ giving us,

$$F(z) = d \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{z}\right)$$

And using $\lim_{z \to 0}F(z)=1$ we get $d=\frac{1}{2}$ (use L' Hospitals rule) and the RHS of (5.68) follows.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to see this is that if we substitute $z=p(1-p)$ in (5.68), the expression becomes the probability that the wealthy gambler will ever reach $k$\$ while (5.67) is the probability he will ever reach $1$\$ (if he keeps tossing a coin with probability $p$ of heads and wins $1$\$ on heads and loses $1$\$ on tails). To reach $k$\$, he has to increase his fortune by $1$\$ $k$ times. And the result follows.