# The value of the sequence $A_{m,n}$ which satisfies a special recurrence equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, recurrence-relations

For a positive integer $m$ and a non-negative integer $n$, find $A_{m,n}$ which satisfies the following :

1. For every $n$, $A_{1,n} = 1$
2. If $n>0$, then $A_{m,n}$ = $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{m-1}A_{m-i,n+i-1}$
3. $A_{m,0} = A_{m-1,0}+\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{m-2}A_{m-i-1,i}$

- I found out that $A_{m,n} = A_{m-1,n+1} + A_{m,n-1}$

Comment: Have you made a spreadsheet or program to compute a bunch of small values?  What did you find?  In 2 you should also require $m \gt 1$.  We need $A_{0,0}$ specified and 3 limited to $m \ge 1$

Comment: Yes, I've computed some values. I also found out that $A_{m,n) = A_{m-1,n+1} + A_{m,n-1}$ @RossMillikan

Comment: That sounds a lot like Pascal's triangle.  Is that what you find?  You should edit that into your post so people don't have to repeat what you have done.

Comment: Actually, the relations in the post are derived by the formula A_{m,n} = A_{m-1,n+1}+A_{m,n-1}. I'll add that on into my post.

Comment: I didn't check the indices, but it looks like you may be using the hockey-stick identity here.

Comment: It's quite similar with the hockey-stick identity, but I think it's slightly different.

Comment: It is [Catalan's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_triangle) (skewed and transposed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed form turns out to be $$\color{blue}{A_{m,n}=\frac{n+2}{n+2m}\binom{n+2m}{m-1}.}\tag{*}\label{results}$$

Observe that, using "2.", we can write "3." as $A_{m,0}=A_{m-1,0}+A_{m-1,1}$ (for $m>1$).

Now we use generating functions. Let $A_n(x)=\sum_{m>0} A_{m,n}x^{m-1}$. Then $$A_0(x)=1+\sum_{m>1}(A_{m-1,0}+A_{m-1,1})x^{m-1}=1+x\big(A_0(x)+A_1(x)\big)\tag{1}\label{initial}$$ and, similarly, for $n>0$ $$A_n(x)=1+\sum_{m>1}(A_{m,n-1}+A_{m-1,n+1})x^{m-1}=1+\big(A_{n-1}(x)-1\big)+x A_{n+1}(x).$$

Thus, $xA_{n+1}(x)-A_n(x)+A_{n-1}(x)=0$, which is a linear recurrence, solved by $$A_n(x)=A_+(x)\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\right)^n+A_-(x)\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\right)^n,\tag{2}\label{general}$$ where $A_+$ and $A_-$ are some functions of $x$ *representable by power series* since $A_0$ and $A_1$ are. And since $A_n$ is a power series (as well) for each $n$, we must have $A_+=0$ identically. Hence $A_-=A_0$. Now  \eqref{general} at $n=1$ gives $A_1$ in terms of $A_0$, which we put it into \eqref{initial}. This gives $A_0$, and \eqref{general} now reads $$A_n(x)=\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\right)^{n+2},$$ which has a [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3064256) expansion (see also [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuss%E2%80%93Catalan_number) for even more general setting) $$A_n(x)=\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\binom{2k+n+2}{k}\frac{n+2}{2k+n+2}x^k.$$

"Renaming" the summation index (according to $k=m-1$), we get the expected \eqref{results}.